# Three20 Build Error

Tags: iphone, ios, three20

I can successfully execute the command:

```
python Three20/src/scripts/ttmodule.py -p test320/Test320.xcodeproj Three20
```

and the project has a file information. But I can not build. I don't know why. Any ideas?

Images:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you included all the necessary frameworks needed for Three20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just comment this code out. This is known issue.

More here :
https://github.com/facebook/three20/issues/802
and :
https://github.com/facebook/three20/pull/809

Comment: No problems. I had to deal with this myself and didn't find to much about it